# django manytoone other side

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a django webapp. I have something like this set up:

```
class Doc(models.Model)
      invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)

class Invoice(models.Model)
      #bla bla bla
```

Can I somehow create a form element that would stand for `invoice.doc_set.all()` ? I want it to be I want it to be a multiple select element. I know I dont want Inline formsets. What I want to see in django admin on Invoice side --> simple Multiple select element with all the instances that can be selected. When selected and saved the particular invoice will become the foreign key instance to them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ModelMultipleChoiceField.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

But I don't think that the admin can manage this type of functionality out of the box. You will probably need to extends the admin form and set the FK by yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I thought there would be or could be another simplier solution to my problem. I did as you suggest. Just hoped there was an easier more django way